# returning a filesize always get 0

Tags: python, filesize, os.path

so basically i have this code that add a line to a python script and then calculate the size of it and it works fine

```
import os
def create_python_script(filename):
  comments = " Start of a new Python program"
  with open(filename,'w') as f :
    f.write(comments)
    f.close
    filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
  return(os.path.getsize(filename))

print(create_python_script("program.py"))
```

and it outputs 30 which is the actual size of the file since its empty and only have that line

now if i change the   `return(os.path.getsize(filename))`with     `return(filesize)` which is logical since `filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)`i actually get the output 0

here is the second code making the change

```
import os
def create_python_script(filename):
  comments = " Start of a new Python program"
  with open(filename,'w') as f :
    f.write(comments)
    f.close
    filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
  return(filesize)

print(create_python_script("program.py"))
```

can someone explain to me why the ouput is 0 ?

thank you

Comment: You don't close the file with `f.close`. That's just a reference to the method object. You can close it with `f.close()`, but it's better to just let the `with` block exit and do its job.

Comment: You haven't actually closed the file (`f.close` does nothing, try `f.close()`) - so all of the data you've written is still in an internal buffer, and hasn't been physically written to the file yet.

Comment: @jasonharper your solution worked thank you

Answer (score 0):

i might be wrong but while the "with" function is open it wont "update the file" so try to remove the getsize from the "with" function

Answer (score 0):

**Corrections**

- I've removed `f.close`, it's not required when you use `with open()`
- Note, indentation of `filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)`

**Working code**

```
import os
def create_python_script(filename):
    comments = " Start of a new Python program"
    with open(filename,'w') as f :
        f.write(comments)

    filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
    return filesize

print(create_python_script("program.py"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason `filesize` returns 0 is very simple. It has nothing to do with scope and/or file closing as the comments suggest. Look at your code, again-

(the `f.close` is removed as first: it does nothing, and second: you don't need to close the file manually when you're using `with open` to open it)

```py
with open(filename,'w') as f :
    f.write(comments)
    filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
  return os.path.getsize(filename)
```

Notice the return, the `getsize` is calculated *after* the file is written and closed, i.e **outside** the `with`. After the `with`, the file has finished writing and it has an actual size that is updated - hence, **this** is the time you should calculate the size.

Now take a look at the alternative-

```py
with open(filename,'w') as f :
    f.write(comments)
    filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
  return filesize
```

Where is the `.getsize` calculated? **before** the file is closed - hence the file hasn't been written, the size is currently 0 because the file was empty before writing to it.

In fact, try this-

```py
with open(filename,'w') as f :
    f.write(comments)
    print(os.path.getsize(filename))
  return os.path.getsize(filename)
```

Output-

```py
0
30
```

See? `.getsize` returns 0 inside the `with` - because that's what it should return.

And *that* is the real reason. Hope this clears out your question. This has absolutely nothing to do with "scopes"